# Does pandas query takes variables names?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multindex dataframe where the middle index is 'Week'. I would like to filter by this and my code looks like this:

```
today = date.today()
this_week = today.isocalendar()[1]'
dt_g.query('Week >= 17 and Week <= this_week')
```

But this returns:
`UndefinedVariableError: name 'this_week' is not defined`

When I put number 19 instead of this_week, query works properly. Also when I print this_week outside the method it returns number 19.

I would like to know why this isn't working properly in this specific example or how can I create query that will filter from week 17 until current week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `@` to let the interpreter know that we are passing a variable to query.

```
dt_g.query('Week >= 17 and Week <= @this_week')
```

**As stated in `pandas docs`**

The query string to evaluate.
You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing them with an ‘@’ character like @a + b.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt_g.query(f'Week >= 17 and Week <= {this_week}')
```

This should work.